# sed remove line containing a string and nothing but; automation using for loop

Tags: sed

Q1: Sed specify the whole line and if the line is nothing but the string then delete

---

I have a file that contains several of the following numbers:

```
1 1
3 1
12 1
1 12
25 24
23 24
```

I want to delete numbers that are the same in each line. For that I have either been using:
`sed '/1 1/d' < old.file > new.file`
OR
`sed -n '/1 1/!p' < old.file > new.file`

Here is the main problem. If I search for pattern '1 1' that means I get rid of '1 12' as well. So for I want the pattern to specify the whole line and if it does, to delete it.

Q2: Automation of question 1

---

I am also trying to automate this problem. The range of numbers in the first column and the second column could be from 1 to 25.

So far this is what I got:

```
for ((i=1;i<26;i++)); do
 sed "/'$i' '$i'/d" < oldfile > newfile; mv newfile oldfile;
done
```

This does nothing to the oldfile in the end. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be more readable with awk:

```
awk '$1 == $2 {next} {print}' oldfile > newfile
```

**Update** based on comment:

If the requirement is to remove lines where the two values are within 1 of each other:

```
awk '{d = $1-$2; if (-1 <= d && d <= 1) next; else print}' oldfile
```

Unfortunately, awk does not have `abs()` (at least nawk and gawk don't)

Comment: This is an excellent answer! In the whole scheme of things it gets me closer to the answer. Just one question. Is is possible to specify a value one less and one more than the value in column two in the regex of awk? So in addition to deleting lines with lets say '2 2', would it be possible to delete '1 2' and '3 2' in a similar expression as above?

Answer (score 1):

Just put the first number in a group (`\([0-9]*\)`) and then look for it with a backreference (`\1`). Since the line to delete should contain *only* the group, repeated, use the `^` to mark the beginning of line and the `$` to mark the end of line. For example, for the following file:

```
$ cat input 
1 1
3 1
12 1
1 12
12 12
12 13
13 13
25 24
23 24
```

...the result is:

```
$ sed '/^\([0-9]*\) \1$/d' input 
3 1
12 1
1 12
12 13
25 24
23 24
```

Comment: Thank you for your excellent suggestion brandizzi! If I could have your patience, I also want to delete values one higher and one lower than the values of the second column. ie. for pattern '2 2' delete '3 2' and '1 2'. This would be done for 1-25. I was using the following loop code: 

for ((i=1;i<26;i++)); do 
 first=$i; second=$(($i+1)); third=$(($i-1)); # variables
 sed '/^'$first' '$i'$/d' <oldfile>newfile; 
 sed '/^'$second' '$i'$/d'<newfile>oldfile; 
 sed '/^'$third' '$i'$/d'<oldfile>newfile; 
 mv newfile oldfile; 
done

Though I think sed is not reading my variables. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Ali: Arithmetic requires something other than regexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with grep:
`grep -E -v "([0-9])*\s\1" testfile`

Look for multiple digits in a row and remember them, followed by a single whitespace, followed by whatever digits you remembered.

Comment: This also matches "1 12" from the sample input -- it would also match "32 21". You need anchors and also move the quantifier into the parentheses: `'^([0-9]+)\s+\1$'`